# Why do I get: "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Tags: c#, file, process, createfile

I tried the following using C#:

```
File.CreateText("x.y");
folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
string dir = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath.ToString();
File.WriteAllText("x.y", dir);
```

But when I run the program it says that the process cannot access the file (x.y) because it is being used by another process.

[At `file.WriteAllText`]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solved a similar problem.  I was using WriteAllText(), constructing a file name from the number of files in the folder, so each file would have a unique name.  The error was baffling because the file was being created and written in a single statement; how could another process be accessing it?  It turns out, multiple THREADS were calling this, and constructing the same file name.  I fixed it using a thread-safe method to generate file names.

Answer (score 5):

File.CreateText returns a StreamWriter opened for you.
If you want to use File.WriteAllText you need to close that stream before.

```
StreamWriter sr =  File.CreateText("x.y");
sr.Close();
```

Or simply do not create the file at all in that point, but just with the following [WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

From WriteAllText on MSDN

> Creates a new file, writes the specified string to the file, and then
>   closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove

```
File.CreateText("x.y");
```

It returns you `StreamWriter` to newly created file which you even don't use or need. [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will work without it

> Creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

The File.CreateText opens the file if it already exists.

So instead of:

```
File.CreateText("x.y");
folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
string dir = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath.ToString();
File.WriteAllText("x.y", dir);
```

I did:

```
if (!File.Exists("x.y"))
{
        File.CreateText("x.y");
}
folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
string dir = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath.ToString();
File.WriteAllText("x.y", dir);
```